# Change in execution of the size of the page in jspdf (vue.js)

Tags: printing, jspdf

How do I change the size of the sheet to print on a pos printer with jspdf (pdf)?.

I create the object like that:

```
doc = new JSPDF({
    orientation: 'portrait',
    unit: 'mm',
    format: [55, 150]
});
```

I add the other popiedades and, sometimes, I spare space. How to save paper by decreasing the size? Or increase it?

I tried changing

```
doc.format = [55, 140]
```

before

```
doc.save ()
```

but nothing happens

I have also tried changing objects with `Objetc.assign()`, but nothing happens.

Comment: Good. I will try to calculate previously the length of the paper that is needed to print and thus, define the size. If someone can help me, I would appreciate it.